# property `children` doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, titanium

My engironment is titanim 6.0.1.GA

It doesn't show the label on Android, while iOS show the label correctly.

```
var descriptionView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:'100%',width:'100%'
    children:[Ti.UI.createLabel({
        wordWrap :true,top:0,
        color:'black',
        text:"my label",
    })]
});
```

It works well both on Android/iOS

```
var descriptionView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:'100%',width:'100%'
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        wordWrap :true,top:0,
        color:'black',
        text:"my label",
});
descriptionView.add(label)
```

I just wonder using children is bad behaivor for andorid?
However it sometimes very useful to simplify the code.

Is there anyone who uses `children` successfully for Android??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the titanium API '**Children**' property is a read only property and it should not be used to set data. It's considered to be good luck as it's working with IOS but with Android we need to be specific with the code.

I would never suggest you to use this coding style to simplify the code, rather you could use the following to simplify and also memory effective way :

```
var descriptionView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:'100%',width:'100%'
});

descriptionView.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
        wordWrap :true,top:0,
        color:'black',
        text:"my label",
}));
```

Good luck,
Cheers

Comment: OK. I give up use children property. THank you for your advice.